# Force a child component to update when the parent state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a `MyList` component that fetches items, allows filtering and sorting. This component is already used in other parts of the apps and it works well. It uses render props to render the items so it accepts a `renderItem` prop of type function.

Now I'm building a simple list to allow item selection using the aforementioned component and I'm checking for the selected state in the render prop `renderItem` method. The problem is that when I change the state of `MySelectableList` the `MyList` component doesn't update because its props does not change (it's always the same bound function `renderProp`). For now I forced the rendering of the child with `this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);` but I don't like it, I know that I can update the child component with `ref` but I don't like it either.

Is there a better method to force the child component to render when the parent **state** changes? Am I doing something wrong?

Full code of `MySelectableList`:

```
class MySelectableList extend Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedItems: [],
        };
        this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.isSelected = this.isSelected.bind(this);
    }

    toggle (item) {
        const newItems = this.state.selectedItems.slice(0);
        const index = newItems.indexOf(item.uuid);
        if (index === -1) {
            newItems.push(item.uuid);
        } else {
            newItems.splice(index, 1);
        }
        this.setState({ selectedItems: newItems });
        // Force MyList to re-render by tricking react that it's different
        this.renderItem = this.renderItem.bind(this);
    }

    isSelected (item) {
        return this.state.selectedItems.includes(item.uuid);
    }

    renderItem (item) {
        return (<MySelectableItem
            key={ item.uuid }
            item={ item }
            toggle={ this.toggle }
            selected={ this.isSelected(item) } />);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                ...
                <MyList renderItem={ this.renderItem } />
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The `MyList` component is connected to redux store using `connect`. I discovered that `connect` is the cause of the `MyList` component missing rendering, using only "vanilla" react component it works correctly.

I reproduced the problem in this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/0mov14nmmp

Comment: Why will it rerender? it is no binding between the parent and child? You're not passing the `state` as `props`.

Comment: Instead of passing the renderItem as props, can you not use pass it as children
`<MyList>
<MySelectableItem >
</MyList>`

Comment: @nitte93user3232918 thanks for your input. I know that it will not rerender and I understand why (`this.renderItem` does not change), I'm asking if there is a nice way (more react friendly) to trigger the render or if I have to change the whole design somehow. I cannot pass `MySelectedItem` as children because the actual items are managed by the child component `MyList`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about  *how to do it more react friendly way*

The nicer way to do this would be:

```
render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyList {...whateeverExtraPropsyouWantToPass}>
                   <MySelectableItem
                       key={ item.uuid }
                       item={ item }
                       toggle={ this.toggle }
                       selected={ this.isSelected(item) } />
                </MyList>
            </div>
        );
```

Then your MyList will look something like this:

```
render () {
        return (
            <div>
               ...//your other MyList code
               ...
               {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
```

This looks more readable, more maintainable and easily debuggble. But I'm sure this is all obvious to you. Since, you asked about `a react friendly way`, this is the most react friendly way you can do.

I would not suggest unnecessary, explicitly trying to render any component. Until and unless it is the only way, which is not the case in your component.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your suggestion but items in my case are fetched and managed by `MyList`, so I cannot instantiate and I cannot access `item` in the parent scope.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the way you implement MyList. React Native FlatList has the same pattern. But why dont you also pass items as a property to the MyList, so it will be like

`<MyList items={this.state. selectedItems} renderItem={this.renderItem} />`

This way MyList will re-render because items property changes. items property is needed as well because I assume that in your MyList component you need to do items.map function right? otherwise how do you know how many items in total you need to render?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately `items` are fetched and managed directly by `MyList` component, I don't know the items in the parent component.